# What option can be chosen in logastash

Tags: logstash

I'm using logstash to parse logs from files, my question is witch option should i choose to collect all my logs without duplicating the data

```
 start_position => 'beginning'
```

or

```
 start_position => 'end'
```

and what is the deference between the two options.
 Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the docs:

> Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end. The default behavior treats files like live streams and thus starts at the end. If you have old data you want to import, set this to ‘beginning’
>
> This option only modifies “first contact” situations where a file is new and not seen before. If a file has already been seen before, this option has no effect.

So if you always want to import the whole file, use `beginning`.  If what you are dealing with is some sort of streaming situation where only the latest stuff matters, use `end`.  It's important that you use `beginning` if you have a log file that changes names from day to day.  Otherwise when logstash sees the next days file for the first time, it'll skip over the beginning of it.

I personally can't think of any situation where you wouldn't want to use `beginning`, but then maybe I'm dense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with 'beginning'  if we stop logstash for a few time and adding some others logs in my file, then we restart it.. Logstash will duplicate all the logs staring by the first line and not adding only the new lines but all the lines.. then the logs will be indexed two time :o so i think using 'begennig only at the first time and then using 'end'

Comment: If that's happening it's because it can't write to your sincedb.  Try setting  `sincedb_path` to someplace you know the user that's running logstash can write to.

Comment: As to why `start_position => beginning` could be a bad idea, consider what happens if you change the input filename pattern. The sincedb filename is by default based on a checksum of the pattern(s), so you'll end up with a "first contact" situation and duplicated logs.